# htop - why duplicate line when I run program?

Tags: linux, monitoring, htop

I used `htop` to check the system monitor.
I run the program `app.py` but I saw 2 line display `app.py` run.
[image]

Is my `app.py` duplicate run?

Comment: What is `app.py` doing?

Comment: hi @Kusalananda, `app.py` just: read a huge data, analysis, handling data,....

Comment: There are two processes named app.py. You see that their process IDs are distinct. This may be an error or it may be by design, depending on the application.